# Get image height via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

In a JavaScript function, I want to get the height of an image. I do:

```
var image_height = $(image).height();
```

Turns out `image_height` is 0, but I'm sure my image doesn't have height 0. Is there a way to extract this height?

Comment: Do you wait for the image to be loaded ? Why don't you simply use `image.height` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate height after image load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(image).load(function(){
      var image_height = $(this).height();
    } );
});
```

Comment: Slow solution. Regular javascript is always faster. -1

Comment: @Christian what do you mean by slow solution?

Comment: jQuery shouldn't be used for this kind of simple task.

Comment: Can you give me time difference between no jQuery and jQuery solutions. Jquery do consider browser before giving you result. In pure javascript it may work in some browser and may fail in others

Answer (score 2):

try outerHeight() as well

var image_height = $(image).outerHeight();

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the dom has been rendered prior to retrieving the height.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var image_height = $(image).height(); 
}):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular JS:

```
var image_height = img.clientHeight
```